# change fragement onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing android application that depends on Fragment, only one activity with multiple fragments

I have called another activity with start for result and I want to replace the fragment but I got the following error

Can not perform this action after `onSaveInstanceStatus`

can anyone please help

Comment: Maybe some code could improve your question.

Comment: Thank you user1767746, I have solved the problem by my team leader and I will share the solution with you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem here was happened because I return back to activity with result and the activity is not resuming yet, so I need to but this part of code in new Handler() in a new thread to wait for some time until resume the activity and then change the fragment

Answer (score 1):

Yes fragments cannot be swapped or replaced etc. during an onActivityResult. Set a boolean or integer value and swap fragments based on that value in the onResume() call of the activity instead.